# How to obtain ServerContext in glassfish 3

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-2.x

I am the "proud" heir of a 12+ year old code base that has been worked on by many engineers over the years. I have been tasked to upgrade our system from glassfish 2.1.1 to glassfish 3.1.2.2. Most everything is compiling fine after pointing to the new glassfish 3 jars, except this one issue that I'm running into. There is a method like this:

```
public boolean isRunningInApplicationServer() {
    return ApplicationServer.getServerContext() != null;
}
```

the compiler can't find 'com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer'. I assume there is a new way to obtain the ServerContext using glassifsh 3. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's tempting to say `return true`, since it's running in an application server... But the method might be there for a reason. Instead of just trying to rewrite it, try to find out what it's supposed to do, and why/if it's needed. Maybe you just can delete it. After all, the code is 12+ years old...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't jut delete it. Some parts of our code need to behave differently if they are running as a stand alone process. That level of refactoring is probably out of scope

Comment: There might be an equivalent for newer versions of Glassfish, but it could be implemented as simple (and more portable) as checking a system property or similar. Set the system property in the JVM options of the application server, and don't set it when running standalone.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue as you.. with that code and other classes. What I have just found is this:

if (((SecurityServicesUtil.getInstance() != null) && SecurityServicesUtil.getInstance().isServer())

The class of GF 3 API is:
com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityServicesUtil from security.jar

it uses internally the class org.glassfish.api.admin.ProcessEnvironment from glassfish-api.jar

hope this help you